# why the first line of datafile is being skipped c++

Tags: c++, arrays, while-loop, data-files

While running this loop for my school assignment, it seems to be skipping the first line of the data file I am pulling from .

Here is the data file
Joe Johnson 89
Susie Caldwell 67
Matt Baker 100
Alex Anderson 87
Perry Dixon 55

The output I am getting is :

Caldwell,Susie                    D
Baker,Matt                    A
Anderson,Alex                    B
Dixon,Perry                    F
Class average 77.25

Here is the code.

```
   #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    #include <fstream>
    #include <iomanip>

    using namespace std;







    int main()
    {
        // Variable declarations: 
        string fName[10];
        string lName[10];
        float grade_Average;
        string file;
        string name;
        int scores[10];
        float sum = 0;
        char grade;
        int i = 0;



        ifstream din;


        // Function body: 

        cout << "Enter the name of the file. " << endl;
        cin >> file;

        din.open(file.c_str());

        if (!din)
        {
            cout << " Cannot open the input file. Please try again." << endl;
            return 0;
        }

        cout << setw(10) << setfill(' ')  << "Name" <<setw(20)<<setfill(' ')<< "Grade" << endl;
        din >> fName[i];
        din >> lName[i];
        din >> scores[i];
        while (!din.eof())
        {

            i++;
            din >> fName[i];
            din >> lName[i];
            din >> scores[i];

            sum = sum + scores[i];


            switch (static_cast<int> (scores[i]/10))
            {
            case 0:
            case 1:
            case 2:
            case 3:
            case 4:
            case 5:
                grade = 'F';
                break;
            case 6:
                grade = 'D';
                break;
            case 7:
                grade = 'C';
                break;
            case 8:
                grade = 'B';
                break;
            case 9:
                grade = 'A';
                break;
            case 10:
                grade = 'A';
                break;
            default:
                cout << "Invalid score." << endl;



            }

            name = lName[i] + ',' + fName[i];
            cout << setw(10) << setfill(' ') << name  << setw(20) << setfill(' ')<<(" ") << grade << endl;


        } 
        grade_Average = sum / i;
        cout << "Class average " << grade_Average << endl;


        din.close();

        return 0;
    }
     // end function main
```

Comment: You read once right before the loop, and then again the first thing in the loop, overwriting any previously read values. This has an effect of discarding the first line - you read it, and then immediately read the second line on top of it.

Answer (score 2):

The first line isn't being skipped, but you never print out any results for it:

```
    din >> fName[i];
    din >> lName[i];
    din >> scores[i];
    while (!din.eof())
    {

        i++;
```

Note that in the first three lines of the above code, you read in values for `fName[0]`, `lName[0]`, and `scores[0]`, but then you increment i (inside the while loop), and never look at those values again.

You'd be better off deleting those three lines, and moving the `i++;` line to the end of your while-loop, instead.